# Generate commands for SQL transaction with Tcl and sqlite

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I am having trouble understanding how to create a SQL command batch say in a list and pass it on to sqlite for execution in a transaction.

Basically what I do now is:

```
sqlite3 db1 $dbFile
db1 eval BEGIN
foreach Key [array names myArray] {
    db1 eval {SQL statement involving $Key}
}
db1 eval COMMIT
```

I was thinking of a means to generate a list with SQL INSERTs and then passing it to *db1 transaction* or *db1 eval*, but this does not seem to work for me. Perhaps I am just making some stupin syntax mistakes. Anyone have a working example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I was right about "stupid mistake".

```
db1 transaction {
    foreach Key [array names myArray] {
        db1 eval {SQL statement involving $Key}
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: That's the correct way to do a transaction that processes an SQL statement for each element of an array.